# Spring @DependsOn with class instead of bean name

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to supply class itself instead of bean name to `@DependsOn`?

I.e. assuming:

```
@Component
class MyComponent {
}
```

Instead of this:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("myComponent")
class Dependent {
}
```

do this:

```
@Component
@DependsOn(MyComponent.class)
class Dependent {
}
```

Alternatively, is there a way to achieve the same functionality using some other annotation or form of Spring configuration?

The reason I'd like this is to make sure this is checked by the compiler, so e.g. class renames would not break this until runtime.

Comment: `@DependsOn` is to manage the order how beans are getting created. What is your use case?

Comment: @Tim Added more info. Right, I'd like to get the ordering, but also make it compile-time checked if possible.

Comment: The checks about the order are done by spring during runtime. You would need to spin up the spring context during a test to ensure all components can be injected. If you rename your class but no the value in the annotation it triggers a compile error. If you properly refactor the class name it wont trigger a compile nor runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is only to have the compiler check such that renaming the `MyComponent`  will not break the things , you can simply assign a customised bean name to `MyComponent` such that its bean name will no longer relies on the default behaviour which is derived from the class name.

Set a constant to refer to this customised bean name, every bean configuration that need to refer to this bean name should refer to this constant.

Code wise it looks likes:

```
@Component(value=MyComponent.beanName)
class MyComponent {

   public static final String beanName = "myComponent"; 
}

@Component
@DependsOn(MyComponent.beanName)
class Dependent {

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken - OK that could work, though it's a bit clumsy as now all bean naming would have to be done manually. For example, nothing prevents two beans having the same bean name and breaking in runtime as well. Though I guess better than just `@DependsOn("myComponent"`.

Comment: Well , the problem of two beans that has the same bean name can be simply prevented from adding a simple integration test that to verify  if the spring context can  started without error which IMO is a basic test that every serious spring project should have..

Comment: +1 for IT, though that depends on the project. E.g. adding `@Conditional` or `@Lazy` can still hide these. Compile-time rules IMHO.